# Why is the new google logo not in CSS?

Tags: css, image, image-size

So, I'm learning CSS and came to know that you can create simple images by using CSS. The new google logo is entirely composed of circles and rectangles, so that its size is much lesser than the old one, which is in line with their mission to get google in underdeveloped countries, with slower internet. My question is, won't using CSS for logo be much smaller in size than using an image

Comment: Are you asking us whether the Google logo could be implemented in CSS and whether that would be smaller? → Go ahead and try it. Or do you want to know **why a multi-national company made the decision not to implement their logo in CSS?!** → Go work for them and talk to the people involved.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's description](https://design.google.com/articles/evolving-the-google-identity/) of the process they went through redesigning their logo, there's a variant of the image that's only 305 bytes. So they wouldn't gain much by converting it to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As always there are multiple ways to solve a problem. Trying to recreate the logo in css is one of them but that's not what CSS is for.

There are multiple ways Google could show their logo:

- As an image: png, jpg, svg

  - As a seperate file
  - Embedded in the html or css document
- As a font
- As you propose, recreate in html and css

Each of these solutions have their benefits and drawbacks. You only mentioned one benefit but their are so many other things you need to check: performance, platforms, accessibility, ...

In general you will notice that just displaying an image gives the best result.